# Using “Google 2 Step Verification” while on vacation

Tags: google-account, security, authentication, multi-factor-auth

I'm using *Google 2-Step Verification* and I'm about to go for vacation. My biggest concern is that I will not have my phone with me and therefor will not be able to receive texts with code whenever I'd like to login.

I generated 10 codes with me, hopefully this will help.

Is that the right thing to do? Or should I do something else instead and/or in addition to that?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and instead of receiving texts, I switched over to the [Google Authenticator App](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1066447?hl=en) on my phone (also works with other services besides Google, like GitHub for example). You should keep the backup codes anyway—they come in handy if you don't have your phone with you, you lose it, or your battery dies etc.

Comment: To clarify, you can run the Google Authenticator app on any Android or iOS device, whether it has data service or not.

Comment: BTW if you log in to your account from Internet cafes and other untrusted computers, you run some risks, although mitigated by Two Factor Authentication. It's safer if you bring your own mobile device or Chromebook.

Comment: There are also Windows/Mac/Chrome apps that allow you to setup your computer as an authenticator. Of course this greatly decreases the security of your account, so use good judgment.

Answer (score 1):

Google Authenticator App is a very good choice but did you lose your device and got locked out of all of your accounts?

For this reason I moved over to use [Authy app](https://www.authy.com/)

- Full Backups
- Multiple Devices
- All your accounts, one app

Manage 2-Step Verification for your online accounts like Gmail, Facebook, Dropbox, LastPass, Evernote, Amazon, and many others! All of them in just one App using Authy.